# Trying to delete the first sheet in each excel file and then copying from each tab to the master workbook with the same tab names

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, what my macro is doing right now is going through a folder and picking each excel file and deleting the first tab which is named some_Accounts and then copy pasting data to the master workbook where the worksheet names match.

I am getting an error on
      " If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then"

Object variable not set or defined. Can someone shed a light on where this is going wrong?

Here is my code

```
Sub ProjectMacro()
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, K As Long
    K = Sheets.Count

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\some files\"
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do While strFilename <> ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & strFilename)

        'loop through each worksheet in the source file
        For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
            'Find the corresponding worksheet in the destination with the same 
            name as the source

            For i = K To 1 Step -1
                t = Sheets(i).Name
                If t = "some_Accounts" Then
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    Sheets(i).Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            Next i

            On Error Resume Next

            Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)

            On Error GoTo 0

            If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then
                lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
                wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy
                wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next wsSrc

        wbSrc.Close False
        strFilename = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line:

```
 Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)
```

Right after shutting off all your errors with

```
 On Error Resume Next
```

Remove that `On Error Resume Next` as that next line that sets `wsDST` is 100% failing so your `wsDst` isn't set and thus you can't get the `wsDst.Name` for you `If` statement.

Why that `Set wsDst` line is failing is a whole other question

Comment: "Why that `Set wsDst` line is failing..." - meaning that there's no match between the source and destination workbooks - I was going to recommend testing if `wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)` exists.

Comment: @BigBen Totally agree. I feel like this might end up in a troubleshooting section to elaborate more, so I think maybe a second question by OP may be appropriate to figure out the new error they introduce/uncover by removing the error handling.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. Sorry a bit new to macro automation. The error then i get is Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' failed. Would this warrant a new question?

Comment: Yes. I believe that should be a new question since it's unrelated. Theoretically `wsSrc.Name` shouldn't throw that error since you are iterating through all worksheets in the workbook. My guess is, to move that `For K .... Next` block to execute before your `For Each wsSrc...` line. Because you are probably setting wsSrc to `some_Accounts` and then deleting it so it no longer exists. If that doesn't fix it though, then pop open a new question so folks can wrap their head around it.

Comment: @JNevill deleting the sheet (`For K....Next`) first was the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312018/not-being-able-to-copy-data-from-each-excel-file-in-a-folder-to-master-workbook#comment89602802_51312632)