# Setting reference to worksheet generates error: Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet'

Tags: excel, vba

My macro is going through a folder and picking each Excel file and deleting the first tab which is named some_Accounts and then copy pasting data to the master workbook where the worksheet names match.

Getting the following error Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' on the following line of code

```
Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)
```

I made sure that the worksheet names are equal.

```
Sub ProjectMacro()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, K As Long
K = Sheets.Count

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
MyPath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\some files\"
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

Do While strFilename <> ""

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & strFilename)

    'loop through each worksheet in the source file
    For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
        'Find the corresponding worksheet in the destination with the same 
        name as the source

        For i = K To 1 Step -1
            t = Sheets(i).Name
            If t = "some_Accounts" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets(i).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next i

        Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)

        On Error GoTo 0

        If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then
            lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
            wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy
            wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next wsSrc

    wbSrc.Close False
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)

probably does not exist

Comment: I made sure to copy the tab name exact as it is to the master workbook

Comment: When you're looping and deleting `Sheets(i)`, you're operating on whatever workbook is currently active. Protect yourself and make it perfectly clear which workbook you're working on by specifying the workbook, as in `wsSrc.Sheets(i)...`. As @Guest indicated, the `wsSrc` object doesn't exist by the time you get to the error line. So you need to check for that condition.

Comment: Why even delete the "some_Accounts" sheet? I noticed you close `wbSrc` without saving changes. Do you just want to skip over that sheet?

Comment: Hello BigBen was it you that told me to put the delete part outside the copy paste part of the code? I did that and it worked, no idea why. But thank you though!

Comment: @Adam I deleted my comment, but yes, if you're deleting a worksheet, do it before you loop through all the worksheets - otherwise you'll run into errors if you later reference the now deleted worksheet.

Comment: Noted. That worksheet was giving me problems because it had a lot of data for no reason (we don't need it) so thats why i put the delete code in there. Thank you

Comment: Instead of deleting it, you could just skip it when you're looping - I noticed you never save `wbSrc` so I'm not sure why you'd delete.

Comment: Because i need it only once to copy data i need and never again. I should modify my code to just skip it, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are looping through all the `Worksheets` in `wbSrc`. When `wsSrc` is the "some_Accounts" sheet, right after you've deleted it within `For i = K to 1... End For`, it no longer exists, and thus `wsSrc` has no `Name` and will throw an error later on. If you're deleting a sheet, do so **before** you loop through all the sheets in a workbook.

But since you are closing `wbSrc` without saving changes, I assume that you don't really need to delete that sheet; you can just skip it as you're looping.

That would look something like this:

```
For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
    If wsSrc.Name <> "some_Accounts" Then
    '... copy and pasting code here
    End If
Next wsSrc
```

Note that you can incorporate a `WorksheetExists` function into your code to make sure that there is a matching sheet in `wbDst`. That's already been provided in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in your code to see if the worksheet exists:

```
If worksheetExists(wbDst, wsDst.Name) = true then
  MsgBox "Exists!"
else
  MsgBox "Does not exist!"
end if

   Public Function worksheetExists(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetNameStr As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    worksheetExists = (wb.Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Name <> "")
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

   End Function
```

Comment: Was able to do this and it showed exists. What i did was copied the delete part of the code to outside the copy code part of the macro. It worked